# Get original values from cumulative sum

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, cumulative-sum

```
>>> test.val.cumsum()
0    11
1    13
2    56
3    60
4    65
Name: val, dtype: int64
```

How do I get the original values from the cumulative sum? I will have to get `[11,2,43,4,5]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the `diff()` Series method (with `fillna` to replace the first value in the series):

```
>>> s = pd.Series([11, 13, 56, 60, 65])
>>> s.diff().fillna(s)
0    11
1     2
2    43
3     4
4     5
dtype: float64
```