# Calculate daily from cumulative sum

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, cumsum

Is there an easy way that doesn't involve a 'manual' loop to take a cumulative sum series to a daily count series?  kind of the opposite of cumsum()?

```
I have the following df
Day  CumSum  
Mon    1
Tue    4
Wed    8
Thu    16
Fri    25
Sat    32
Sun    43
```

I want to fill an additional column with daily values

```
Day   CumSum   Daily 
Mon     1      1      
Tue     4      3      
Wed     8      4      
Thu     16     8      
Fri     25     9      
Sat     32     7      
Sun     43     11
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get original values from cumulative sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26870116/get-original-values-from-cumulative-sum)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of `.diff()` here, and then fill the `NaN` of the first record with the corresponding value in the `CumSum` column:

```
df['Daily'] = df['CumSum'].diff().fillna(df['CumSum'])
```

For the given sample data, this gives us:

```
>>> df
   Day  CumSum
0  Mon       1
1  Tue       4
2  Wed       8
3  Thu      16
4  Fri      25
5  Sat      32
6  Sun      43
>>> df['Daily'] = df['CumSum'].diff().fillna(df['CumSum'])
>>> df
   Day  CumSum  Daily
0  Mon       1    1.0
1  Tue       4    3.0
2  Wed       8    4.0
3  Thu      16    8.0
4  Fri      25    9.0
5  Sat      32    7.0
6  Sun      43   11.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Reverse the existing cumulative sum column so it's decreasing, then run `cumsum()` on it, then reverse it to get the original order.

```
np.cumsum(x[::-1])[::-1]
```